# AWS CentOS 7 trying to install failed to start VNC server : with configured resource limit was exceeded

Tags: centos7, vnc

i followd this tutorial :
https://www.tecmint.com/install-and-configure-vnc-server-in-centos-7/

to install desktop and connected it via vnc from my windows PC using VNC viewer 
but im getting this error in the : sudo systemctl start vncserver@:1 stage 
im doing all from my user centos which is the main user im using with sudo enabled :
my /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service looks like this :

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

# Clean any existing files in /tmp/.X11-unix environment
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l centos -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"
PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

this is the info :

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1828 Apr  6 16:25 /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service
```

now im trying to start the vnc server :

```
[centos@ip-10-0-0-111 ~]$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
[centos@ip-10-0-0-111 ~]$ sudo systemctl start vncserver@:1
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1- change **Type=forking** to **Type=simple**

2- change to PIDFile=/home/**centos**/.vnc/%H%i.pid